# C#: Cannot set the Contact-Attribute "targetAddress" with my DirectoryEntry - Connection

Tags: c#, active-directory, contacts

I want to create a Contact-Object in a specific OU in our AD with some Attributes:

sn, givenName, mail, description, displayname, proxyAddresses and targetaddress.

I found lots of examples how to set the Attributes for a Contact-Object in Active Directory with C# and I`m able to create the Object with all Attributes except "targetaddress".

Could someone please Point me in the right Direction for this. Thank you!

```
        public void CreateContact2(string Vorname, string Nachname, string EmailAdresse, string Beschreibung, string myDomainPath) 
    {
        string CN = Vorname + " " + Nachname;
        string mailNickName = EmailAdresse.Remove(EmailAdresse.IndexOf("@"));
        string EmailAdresse2 = "SMTP:" + EmailAdresse;
        DirectoryEntry directoryEntry;
        try
        {
            directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://myDomainPath") 
            directoryEntry.RefreshCache();
            DirectoryEntry contact = directoryEntry.Children.Add("CN=" + CN, "Contact");
            contact.Properties["sn"].Value = Nachname;
            contact.Properties["givenName"].Value = Vorname;
            contact.Properties["mail"].Value = EmailAdresse;
            contact.Properties["description"].Value = Beschreibung;
            contact.Properties["displayName"].Value = Nachname + ", " + Vorname;
            contact.Properties["proxyAddresses"].Add(EmailAdresse2);    
            contact.Properties["targetaddress"].Value = EmailAdresse2;    
            contact.CommitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Do some error processing
            var msg = e.Message.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("Fehler in Funktion CreateContact():" + msg);
        }
    }
```

The Contact-Object creates fine if I create it without the `targetaddress-Attribute`

But with it I´m

> getting System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: “The specified
>   directory service attribute or value does not exist”

failure. Any Ideas?

Comment: It's not caseSensitive is it?

Answer (score 0):

I had he same issue , what i did is to restart and run Visual Studio as Administrator . It may be due to not having enough privileges to run some `COM` Methods

Comment: @Jayendran: Thank you, I will try it.

Comment: I don‘t think so. I tried nearly everything, including case sensitive Combinations - but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much Guys! 
I had found the answer by myself and . It was my mistake. The attribute wasn´t right delegated.